# Ajax in a forEach loop with unexpected output

Tags: javascript

Why is the value of index in the output below not 3 for all console.logs? I would expect:

1. The forEach loop calls ajax 4 times before a response is returned by any of the requests. index = 3.
2. A response is returned, the success callback runs and during the execution phase, the scope chain is checked for index which is already 3.

I'm assuming there's no chance that a response is returned fast enough for the success callback to run when index is not 3.

```
campaigns = [1, 2, 3, 4];

campaigns.forEach((campaign, index) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: apiURL,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('index: ', index);
        }
    });
});
```

**Output (different every time as asynchronous):**

```
index: 2
index: 1
index: 3
index: 0
```

Comment: index is a parameter with scope only for each forEach iteration. It doesn't exist outside of that scope. Therefore within each iteration it has its own value (0, 1, 2, 3). It doesn't remain as 3 after the foreach. Since the functions are async, you will get the consoles in the async result order.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I spent hours thinking about this and completely overlooked that... thank you for putting me at peace. If you post that as an answer I will choose it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` is a *parameter* passed to each iteration of the callback - that parameter won't change on its own. It's not like a `for` loop where each iteration can change a shared `i` variable.

If you wanted to emulate a `for (var i = 0...` loop, where `i` is reassigned to `3` by the end, you would need another outer variable, and explicitly reassign it on each iteration, for example:

```
const campaigns = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let campaignIndex = 0;
campaigns.forEach((campaign, index) => {
    campaignIndex = index;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: apiURL,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('campaignIndex: ', campaignIndex);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, ajax call is asynchronous and forEach is syncronous. To avoid the situation, Use Recursion or Use neo-async library to control the flow.

1. [neo-async (each, waterfall, eachSeries)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo-async)